# im new in node.js and express im working on node variables

Tags: node.js

in command line if I run `NODE_ENV=development nodemon server.js`.

The cmd is showing the following error :

> ERROR: NODE_ENV=development : The term 'NODE_ENV=development' is not
>   recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
>   program. Check the spelling of the  name, or if a path was included,
>   verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
>   + NODE_ENV=development nodemon server.js
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (NODE_ENV=development:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I also tried

```
set NODE_ENV=development nodemon server.js
```

or

```
NODE_ENV=development&&nodemon server.js
```

to set `NODE_ENV=development` but none of this command are working {my os:windows 10 ,editor visual studio}

Comment: What operating system?  What command shell?

Comment: windows 10, visual studio

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
set NODE_ENV=development&& nodemon server.js
```

NOTE: No space between `development&&`

Comment: they updated in windows this is the way my node enviroment working: $Env:NODE_ENV='development' ; node server.js